# new code disables ability to use escape to quit

Tags: javascript, psychopy

I added the following code to move a stimulus on the screen, and I just noticed that this seems to disable the ability to escape the code with the 'escape' key anywhere in the script. I am still very new to Javascript, any pointers would be appreciated.

```
//the following appears a few time throughout the script 
// check for quit (typically the Esc key)
if (psychoJS.experiment.experimentEnded ||
  psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys({ keyList: ['escape'] }).length > 0) {
  return quitPsychoJS('The [Escape] key was pressed. Goodbye!', false);
}

// and then later in the script

// FRR ----- manual entry BEGIN; copy this before "function TestRoutineBegin(trials) {" 
// code to move stimulus
var xforce;
spacepressed = 0; // reset each trial
xforce = 0; // initially set speed ('force') to 0. It increases in steps of 1 as long as key is down

function resetXforce (event) {
  xforce = 0; // if finger has been lifted, go back to speed 0
}

function getKeyResponse (event) { // check for responses
  //psychoJS.eventManager.clearEvents({eventType:'keyboard'});
  var thisResp = psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys();
  console.log(thisResp);

  if (spacepressed == 0) {
    if ('left' == thisResp[0]) {
      xforce--;  // decrease angle with increasing acceleration the longer key pressed
      angle = (angle + xforce); //plus not minus here since xforce may become negative
      myx = (0.25 * Math.sin((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
      myy = (0.25 * Math.cos((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
      //smallcircle2.setPos([myx, myy]);
      image_on_circ_test.setPos([myx, myy]);

    }
    if ('right' == thisResp[0]) {
      xforce++; //increase angle with increasing acceleration the longer key pressed
      angle = (angle + xforce);
      myx = (0.25 * Math.sin((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
      myy = (0.25 * Math.cos((((Math.PI * 2) * angle) / 360)));
      //smallcircle2.setPos([myx, myy]);
      image_on_circ_test.setPos([myx, myy]);
    }

    if ('space' == thisResp[0]) {
      LocCol2 = 'white';  // if response locked with spacebar
      //document.removeEventListener("keydown", getKeyResponse); //once spacebar is pressed, dont except any more input
      spacepressed = 1;//new 28.05 15:55
    }

    /* if (psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys({keyList:['space']}).length > 0) {
      LocCol2 = 'white'  // if response locked with spacebar
      spacepressed = 1;
      }*/

    psychoJS.eventManager.clearEvents({ eventType: 'keyboard' });
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', getKeyResponse); //tried keydown as well, with the same problem
window.addEventListener('keyup', resetXforce);

//  FRR------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: some small things that aren't about your actual problem: add your event listeners to `document`, not `window`. Also, compare with `===`, not `==`. The first is true equality, the second is "equal after we try to do type conversion to _something_ that works" which 99.999% of the time is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- I will try that to make sure there are no other issued.  'Hacked' my original  by adding another instance of 
"    // check for quit (typically the Esc key)
    if (psychoJS.experiment.experimentEnded || psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys({keyList:['escape']}).length > 0) {
      return quitPsychoJS('The [Escape] key was pressed. Goodbye!', false);
    }
" to the beginning of the function, but I am not quite sure I understand why it works

Comment: If you solve your own question in 5 minutes of posting, you can safely delete your question: it wasn't something you needed help with (even if it _was_ something you had to write out to get your own brain into figuring-it-out mode =)

Comment: well, but I simply hacked it and did not understand why it works :-)

Comment: You don't want to comment that you "solved it" if all you did was hack around it without understanding the actual solution. If you think you or even future visitors may still benefit from a real answer: leave the question up, and instead of a comment that says you solved it, edit the post to say "if I do this: [...] things _seem_ to work, but I don't understand why" so that it's clear what answer you're looking for, or if you don't think it'll be useful: time to delete it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - thanks, I changed my wording to make clearer it was not really a solve!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `getKeyResponse()` function is always clearing all keyboard events:

```js
function getKeyResponse (event) {
  ...
  if (spacepressed == 0) {
    ...
    psychoJS.eventManager.clearEvents({ eventType: 'keyboard' });
  }
}
```

I would add a check for escape key at the beginning of that function:

```js
function getKeyResponse (event) {
  ...

  // new addition
  if (psychoJS.eventManager.getKeys({ keyList: ['escape'] }).length > 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (spacepressed == 0) {
    ...
    psychoJS.eventManager.clearEvents({ eventType: 'keyboard' });
  }
}
```